# How often should I feed a pregnant cat?

Tags: cats, feeding, strays, pregnancy

A stray cat adopted us a few months back. Initially, we thought it was a boy but then discovered that it's a girl and expecting kittens.

I have never had a cat before and I am learning on the go about them, but she seems to be hungry around the clock. I give her something to eat and literally half an hour later she comes asking for food again.

I am really worried. Please help me what to do? What should I be feeding her, how much, and how often?

I haven't even begun to think what happens when the kittens come!

Answer (score 3):

I always let pregnant queens eat as much as they like. You want a healthy well fed queen and fat little kittens.

Some cats will overeat and start to become obese but this is less of a risk with outdoor cats as they they get more exercise and typically have intestinal parasites. Also it is much better to have a slightly overweight queen Vs. a malnourished one.

The chance of complications and birth defects increase dramatically with malnourished queens.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually I have never had a pet before and I don't know much about caring for them. I am worried about a few things: 1)I don't know how far along is she, but she seems nearing her due date and wants a safe place, How can I help her with it? 2)Although she asks for food from us and sleeps on our sofa, she still wanders a lot which means going outside and collecting dirt(scavenging from the trash cans), then the girl comes back and rubs her against us(unhealthy for us!).please give me some tips about this too.

Comment: another thing if you would, which would b preferrable between commercial food or homemade stuff as food for her.she is very choosy:(

Comment: @AaymanKhalil commercial food is best. Making your own is complicated and you would need to add things like taurine. 1) she will find a place she likes. You can put a cardboard box in a closet but she may or may not use it. 2) If you let her out she may have the kittens outside, can keep her inside?

Answer (score 1):

Stray cats do eat for as long as there is food, so you need to limit the amount of food you give.

You can give about 150 grams of wet food 3 times a day.

Or you can give about 100 grams of dry food 3 times a day and remember to give the cat a bowl of water.

If you give more food than this, the cat risks getting diarrhea from overeating.

You do not need to give a larger amount of food when the kittens are born.

When the kittens get older the mother will bring them with her to where the food is.

IMPORTANT:
Please remember to get the cats trapped and neutered/spayed as soon as possible, several organisations can help you with this.
There is one thing the world does not need and it is more feral cats, so be responsible.

Comment: please tell me the what is wet food and what is dry food?I have never had a cat before so I don't  know anything, and about the quantity, do I have to divide 100gms in three portions?

Comment: cat food is normaly sold in grocerystores,wet food is canned food and dry food is kibbles sold in bags.it is best to split the food into portions and not give it all at once.where do you live?

Comment: I live in Pakistan.

Comment: if cat food is not avaliable in your local shop you have to buy it in a pet shop or on the net.cats need different types of food than humans and dogs need.

Comment: If you live in Pakistan it might be harder to measure because you are giving her human food not cat food (which tends to be identical). Give her whatever (human-like) food you are giving and keep an eye on her body fat. If she gets fat give her a bit less. I wouldn't try to make her lose weight while pregnant.